# Doctype XHTML 1.0 - selecting the language

Tags: xhtml, doctype

Which is correct?

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ro" lang="ro">`

or

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ro-RO" lang="ro-RO">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. There is no practical difference since Romanian does not have multiple national varieties of the language defined by the ISO standard.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean only `ro` is correct? A quick search finds [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that has `ro` and `ro-mo` but not `ro-ro`.

Comment: I can't find the document I was looking at earlier. The most recent guide linked is http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/ … but it is more complicated than a simple table and I don't have the tuits to deal with it right now. I may take a closer look in the morning.